# Mediawiki 1.27.0 changePassword.php Parse error

Tags: php, mediawiki, parse-error

I am trying to use the `changePassword.php` command in MediaWiki 1.27.0 in order to change a user password. Unfortunately I get the following error message:

```
<br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in
<b>/wiki/maintenance/changePassword.php</b> on line <b>56</b><br />
```

Even the `php changePassword.php --help` command results in the same error (see [MediaWiki manual page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:ChangePassword.php))...

Details of the system:

- MediaWiki 1.27.0
- PHP 5.6.27 (cgi-cgi)
- MySQL 5.6.32-78.1-log
- ICU 4.2.1

Answer (score 0):

You are using PHP 5.3 or older. MediaWiki 1.27 [requires](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki_1.27#Breaking_changes) PHP 5.5+; most notably, it has switched to short array syntax which is a [PHP 5.4 feature](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php). The [line](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki/blob/REL1_27/maintenance/changePassword.php#L56) where you get the error uses short array syntax.

Chances are you have misconfigured the web server and the web and CLI PHP version are different.

Comment: thanks for your answer. It is PHP 5.6.27 (check out the original post under *Details of the system")

Comment: As I said, you probably misconfigured your system and it's using different versions of PHP depending on how you invoke it.